# Issue with BYTETracker initialization in live tracking script

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision, object-tracking

I'm facing a `TypeError` when trying to initialize the `BYTETracker` in my live tracking script using the ByteTrack library. The error specifically occurs in the `__init__` method of the `BYTETracker` class.

Here's the relevant part of my code:

```
trackers = [BYTETracker(ByteTrackArgument), BYTETracker(ByteTrackArgument), BYTETracker(ByteTrackArgument)]
```

And the error message I'm encountering is:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'type' and 'float'
```

I've attempted to resolve it by creating an instance of `ByteTrackArgument` like this:

```
trackers = [BYTETracker(ByteTrackArgument()), BYTETracker(ByteTrackArgument()), BYTETracker(ByteTrackArgument())]
```

However, the issue persists. It's worth noting that I'm utilizing `FaceDetectorYN` from OpenCV for face detection in my script.

Any insights on what might be causing this error, especially in conjunction with the use of `FaceDetectorYN`, and how to address it?

Additional Context:

- I'm using the ByteTrack library for live tracking. [link](https://pypi.org/project/bytetracker/)
- The error occurs in the `__init__` method of the `BYTETracker` class.
- I'm passing an instance of `ByteTrackArgument` to the `BYTETracker` constructor.
- Face detection is performed using `FaceDetectorYN` from OpenCV. [link](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d0/dd4/tutorial_dnn_face.html)

here is my full code :

```
import cv2
from bytetracker import BYTETracker
import numpy as np

print("OpenCV version", cv2.__version__)

class ByteTrackArgument:
    track_thresh = 0.5
    track_buffer = 50
    match_thresh = 0.8
    aspect_ratio_thresh = 10.0
    min_box_area = 1.0
    mot20 = False

MIN_THRESHOLD = 0.5  # Adjust this threshold as needed

# Initialize ByteTrackArgument
byte_track_argument = ByteTrackArgument()

# Initialize BYTETracker
trackers = [BYTETracker(ByteTrackArgument()), BYTETracker(ByteTrackArgument()), BYTETracker(ByteTrackArgument())]
def start_webcam_tracking():
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  # Use 0 for default webcam, or provide the webcam URL

    if not cap.isOpened():
        print("Error: Could not open the camera.")
        return

    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if not ret:
            print("Error: Could not read frame from the camera.")
            break

        # Face detection code
        detector = cv2.FaceDetectorYN.create(r"C:\Users\gratu\live tracker\face_detection_yunet_2023mar.onnx", "", (2200, 1200), score_threshold=MIN_THRESHOLD)
        img_W = int(frame.shape[1])
        img_H = int(frame.shape[0])
        detector.setInputSize((img_W, img_H))

        detections = detector.detect(frame)[1]

        if detections is not None:
            for detection in detections:
                x, y, width, height = map(int, detection[:4])
                cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + width, y + height), (0, 255, 0), 2)

                # Update the tracker with face bounding boxes
                tracker.update(np.array([[x, y, x + width, y + height]]), [frame.shape[0], frame.shape[1]])

        # Get tracked results from BYTETracker
        online_targets = tracker.get_online_targets()

        if online_targets is not None:
            for target in online_targets:
                x, y, x2, y2 = target  # Modify this part based on BYTETracker's output format
                cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x2, y2), (255, 0, 0), 2)

        cv2.imshow('Webcam with Face Detection and Tracking', frame)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_webcam_tracking()
```

this was the tutorial that i tried to replicate, they have used yolox for person detection, I tried to do the same for face detection

[link](https://www.datature.io/blog/introduction-to-bytetrack-multi-object-tracking-by-associating-every-detection-box)